# Re-purpose 1TB Ssd

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, ssd

Old HP Envy laptop had 1TB SSD (1 year old).
I cloned it to a 1TB HDD and swapped them, so now the old laptop is working fine off the HDD and the SSD with everything still on it is free.

My new HP OMEN laptop has a 256 GB PCIe® NVMe™ M.2 SSD plus a 1TB HDD

I want to replace the 1TB HDD in the OMEN with the 1TB SSD from the ENVY and if possible, leave the data on it and any programs that might still run from it. I won't need Windows on it. I don't know what I should delete ...like if there is anything in App Data that should be kept etc.

Sure could use some good advice on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specfify which drive you want to boot from, then once booted, go through the process of deleating windows from your machine... AppData contains the files for the applicatons that run from that drive.